# Excel is it possible to increment a refrence to another sheet inside a formula?

Tags: excel

my problem is exactly as what the title sais.

I have been trying for years to increment a refrence to another sheet inside a formula by draging down the cell, this way i dont have to manually change every number myself.

In case this does not seem clear i will give you an example. 
(and im sorry in advance if my formula is messy, i've learnt excel on my own)

This is one of my failed solutions:

```
=IF("Activity"&A3&"!$A$3"="";"Not Registered";"Activity"&A3&"!$A$3")

=IF("Activity"&A4&"!$A$3"="";"Not Registered";"Activity"&A4&"!$A$3")

=IF("Activity"&A5&"!$A$3"="";"Not Registered";"Activity"&A5&"!$A$3")

=IF("Activity"&A6&"!$A$3"="";"Not Registered";"Activity"&A6&"!$A$3")
```

This is the problem:

```
=IF(Activity1!$A$3="";"Not Registered";Activity1!$A$3)

=IF(Activity1!$A$3="";"Not Registered";Activity1!$A$3)

=IF(Activity1!$A$3="";"Not Registered";Activity1!$A$3)

=IF(Activity1!$A$3="";"Not Registered";Activity1!$A$3)
```

This is what i am trying to do:

```
=IF(Activity1!$A$3="";"Not Registered";Activity1!$A$3)

=IF(Activity2!$A$3="";"Not Registered";Activity2!$A$3)

=IF(Activity3!$A$3="";"Not Registered";Activity3!$A$3)

=IF(Activity4!$A$3="";"Not Registered";Activity4!$A$3)
```

Not a problem to manually change when you only have 4 activities, but i'm planning to add over a hundred.

Thanks in advance!

/Robin

Comment: I might add that in my failed solution the values of A3, A4, A5, A6 [...] and so on is an increasing number 1,2,3,4 [...] which i've draged out a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Indirect()`.  I don't know where these formulas are placed, but I am assuming you are putting in in a cell in row 3, then dragging down:

```
=IF(INDIRECT("Activity"&A3&"!$A$3")="";"Not Registered";INDIRECT("Activity"&A3&"!$A$3"))
```

Comment: Glad that my and @extensionhelp have solutions that work!  (You can choose one of them (whichever you feel best answers the question), and mark as The Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the INDIRECT formula for this. It's a way to combine text and variables to create a sheet or cell reference.

```
=IF(INDIRECT("'Activity"&ROW(B3)&"'!$A$3")="","Not Registered",INDIRECT("'Activity"&ROW(B3)&"'!$A$3"))
```

The `ROW(B3)` portion evaluates to 3, but you can change it to wherever the increment needs to start.